# SonarQube 8.1.0 is complaining about Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value

Tags: java, sonarqube, option-type

I get the error message: "Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value"

But as you can see in the image there is a isPresent() check right before that line.

Is this a bug of SonarQube?

-

[image]

Comment: @amer `Optional` does not have an `getId()`-method.

Comment: Strictly speaking, when you call `component.getId()` for the *second* time, you can't assume that it will give the same `Optional` instance you called `isPresent()` on. I can't check whether this fixes it, because mine doesn't raise the problem

Comment: If @ernest_k's statement holds true, it should be preventable by extracting some `Optional<String> id = component.getId();`

Comment: @ernest_k had the same issue and that fixed it.

Comment: It's honestly better to do : `component.getId().orElse(/*something from your else*/);`

Comment: @amer if you want an alternative value, then yes. If you, however, want to branch the control flow, then this is not possible.

Comment: On a different note, it's a poor practice to keep `Optional` type attributes defined in classes. I wonder if `getId` is just a getter, why Sonar wouldn't warn you for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

ernest_k is right: (Thank you!)

> Strictly speaking, when you call component.getId() for the second
>   time, you can't assume that it will give the same Optional instance
>   you called isPresent() on.

So I changed the code to:

```
Optional<String> optionalId = component.getId();
if (optionalId.isPresent()) {
     String id = optionalId.get();
     // ...
}
```